# Prevent "duplication" of test code just because a parameter is different

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

In my tests suite, I have different tests for integration and for stability.

For example,

```
@pytest.mark.integration
def test_integration_total_devices(settings, total_devices):
    assert total_devices == settings['integration']['nodes']['total']

@pytest.mark.stability
def test_stability_total_devices(settings, total_devices):
    assert total_devices == settings['stability']['nodes']['total']
```

As you can notice, it's exactly the same code, just reading a different parameter from the config.

How can I prevent this situation of duplicating the code? The value of the settings is different, so I can't just:

```
@pytest.mark.integration
@pytest.mark.stability
def test_integration_total_devices(settings, total_devices):
    assert total_devices == settings['nodes']['total']
```

I forgot to mention (thanks @dzejdzej to remind me) that it seems pytest parametrize doesn't do the trick. It works when I want to run both "marks", but the purpose of the mark is to be able to just run the tests of one of them independently, for example, `pytest -m integration`. However, as far as I tested, whenever I set parametrize it will run both.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('type', (
    pytest.param('stability', marks=pytest.mark.stability),
    pytest.param('integration', marks=pytest.mark.integration),
))
@pytest.mark.integration
@pytest.mark.stability
def test_total_devices(settings, total_devices, type):
    assert total_devices == settings[type]['nodes']['total']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at pytest parametrize https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

It should be possible to do sth along these lines:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('area,total_devices', (
    pytest.param('stability', 10, marks=pytest.mark.stability),
    pytest.param('integration', 15, marks=pytest.mark.integration),
))
def test_integration_total_devices(area, total_devices):
    assert total_devices == settings.get(area)['nodes']['total']
```

Comment: but I want to run just any of them, not both. This way, `test_integration_total_devices` is called twice, one with `stability` and the other with `integration`, even though I run `pytest -m integration`

Comment: Strange, it works for me: `1 failed, 1 deselected in 0.02 seconds`.

Comment: are you running just `pytest` or `pytest -m integration` ?? it's not the same.

Comment: wtf, just found out what's going on. It's mixing the tests and the parameter. For example, `pytest -m integration` is running `test_total_devices[stability]`, and `pytest -m stability` is running `test_total_devices[integration]`  any idea why??

Comment: I'll open a different question for this matter, your answer definitively answers mine.